# AC fuse sizing and type for a power entry module

Tags: power, fuses

I have [this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1719207.pdf) power entry module with a 6A rated current. The module needs two fuses to be installed. The exact model is:

FN 286B 6-06 and at the bottom of page 2 the rated current is given as 6A at 40°C and 7.2A at 25°C.

The data-sheet is not recommending the factor for the fuse current sizing and the type of the fuse. It only mentions the dimensions of the fuse.

I couldn't find consistent information about this. I thought a 10A slow fuse would be too big for this. What current rated fuse and type would be suitable roughly for this module? Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: It depends on the load . If it’s a slow starting motor or large cap. bank use SloBlo otherwise not.

Comment: You need to size the fuse for the weakest link (wire, PCB trace, connector pin, etc).